# How to override android turn off mobile function?

Tags: android, android-studio

i am developing an anti_theft application in which i want that if a particular option is turn on,then after this anytime a user long press  phone button to turn off mobile.then after pressing turn off option,mobile should not be turn off but a particular option should be performed e.g  siren in load volume etc. how can we do it.?

Comment: Just so you know - you cannot do this on a normal (non-rooted) device. The action of the power button is fully controlled by the Android OS - there's no way for an App to intercept or disable what action it takes.

Comment: ok thell me if mobile is rooted then how we can do it..?